# What does this "psql (9.4.8, server 9.3.23)" mean?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I need to upgrade my postgresql from 9.x to 10 on linux mint 17.2 but I do not know how to do it properly without losing my data.
I find a tutorial that I want to follow, but when I put:

```
~ $ psql -U postgres
```

I get :

```
psql (9.4.8, server 9.3.23)
Type "help" for help.
postgres=#
```

when the tutorial author get:

```
psql (9.6.5)
```

only.

So what does my output mean? It is version 9.4.8 I have or 9.3.23 ?
Do you have a simple tutorial to update postgresql and pg_admin also if possible? I ask just to know the meaning and to be sure about what I am ready to do

Comment: It means you have psql 9.4.8, and you are running postgres server 9.3.23. Apparently the tutorial author was using 9.6.5.

Comment: thanks  @larsks but what may I update from 2? server or client? and why both (server and client (?) ) have not same version? How can I get 10 version for both?

Comment: does Mint use the Debian `pg_cluster` subsystem or does it just do standard installs?  which packages does your package manger show to be installed?

Comment: Sorry @Jasen , I cannot be sure about answer. I am not pro linux. I am learning it to be honest. Let me check and come back to you

Comment: Linux mint is based on Debian @Jasen  I think

Answer (score 3):

The command-line client program `psql` can be installed independently from the Postgres server software. For instance, you might have it on your PC to connect to a central database server.

The message is saying that the version of `psql` you executed is version `9.4.8`, but the PostgreSQL server you connected to is version `9.3.23`.

The main thing you are upgrading is the database server, so the `9.3.23` is the most important. This is the one you need to think about in terms of data migration, major feature changes, etc.

However, it would be sensible to upgrade your `psql` client at the same time, so that you're not connecting to a server which is newer than the client. This is probably as simple as upgrading an additional package.

Indeed, if using a backup and restore, it's recommended to upgrade the client *before* the server, as newer versions of `pg_dump` (which will almost certainly be the same version as `psql`) may have improvements which apply even when connecting to older servers.

In short:

1. Upgrade your Postgres client tools package from 9.4.8 to 10.x
2. Proceed with the upgrade of your Postgres *server* from 9.3.23 to 10.x

Comment: Your answer helps me to understand more. Now I update client, I am trying to do same thing for server.

Answer (score 0):

The first number is you psql client version. The second (server) number is the version of the server you have connected to. The server version can also be confirmed by querying `select version();`.

Answer (score 0):

the message means that you have the `psql` command-line client ofversion 9.4 and connected to a 9.3 server. there's no major problems with this setup. about the only problem would be the on-line SQL syntax help (`\h`) might be slightly wrong.

To upgrade debian (and presumably ubuntu and mint) very little effort is needed.

install the postgresql 10 then

```
pg_dropcluster 10 main
pg_upgradecluster 9.3 main
```

The first command drops the empty 10 cluster, the second performs the upgrade which copies all your data over to a new cluster.

with no speed-up options given (as above) pupgradecluster will leave your 8.3.x install intact but disabled and present you with a 10.x instance in its place.

Comment: When you say "install the postgresql 10", you are talking about client, am I right? So how to update the server?

Comment: After update I get : `psql (10.4 (Ubuntu 10.4-2.pgdg14.04+1), server 9.3.23)`

Comment: inatall the server too,  then run dropcluster and upgradecluster

Comment: Ok but please I cannot find the right command for the postgresql server update / installation... I turn around. I find the same command that I have used previously to update the client: `sudo apt-get install postgresql-10` . So what is the right way? Can you help?

Comment: This is what I get now when I try to start or restart postgres `*No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"`

Comment: Finally I loose all my data. and I always get server 9.3 when starting a new version. :(